# Solution of a singular integral equation using interpolation and truncated methods

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to code the following integral equation to find the solution numerically using Mathematica.

First we define the following functions:

```
phi[x_]:=Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1}}, 0]
```

```
psi1[x_] := (phi[2 x-1] - phi[2 x]);
```

```
psijk[x_, j_, k_] := (Sqrt[2])^j psi1[-2^j x - k]
```

```
f[x_] := 1/1155 (112 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + x (144 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + x (1155 + 256 (-1 + x)^(3/4) - 1280 x^(3/4) - (1155 + 512 (-1 + x)^(3/4)) x + 1024 x^(7/4))));
```

```
exactsoln[x_] := x^2 (1 - x);
```

I am trying to solve the following integral equation for `u (x)` (numerically). where

```
u[x] + Integrate[(x - t)^(-1/4)*u[t], {t, 0, x}] - 
   Integrate[(x - t)^(-3/4)*u[t], {t, 0, 1}] = f[x];
```

where  `f[x]` is defined as above. 
  Here is the numerical scheme. The approximated solution 
`\approx[x]` which can be written as

```
approxsoln[x_, n_] := 
 Sum[c[j, k]*psijk[x, j, k], {j, 0, n}, {k, -2^n, 2^n - 1}]
```

Then, we will end up by

```
Sum[c[j, k]*(psijk[x, j, k] - 
     Integrate[(x - t)^(-1/4)* psijk[t, j, k], {t, 0, x}] - 
     Integrate[(x - t)^(-1/4)* psijk[t, j, k], {t, 0, 1}]), {j, 0, n}, {k, -2^n, 2^n - 1}];
```

I think it is worth to try for `n=10` first.

Comment: Where to find  the definition `psijk[t, j, k]`

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Thank you. I have added it in the question and here it is for you `psi1[x_] := (phi[2 x] - phi[2 x - 1]);psijk[x_, j_, k_] := Piecewise[{{(Sqrt[2])^j psi1[2^j x - k], 0 <= j}, {2^j psi1[2^j (x - k)], j < 0}}]`

Comment: I tried to `Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}]` , but nothing is plotted.  Probably `f[x]`is wrong, perhaps `(-1+x)^...` has to be substituted by `(1-x)^..`?  Also I suppose an error in the integral equation, I think it should be `u[x] - Integrate[(x - t)^(-1/4)*u[t], {t, 0, x}] -    Integrate[(t-x)^(-1/4)*u[t], {t, x, 1}] = f[x];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numerical solution of a singular integral equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198675/numerical-solution-of-a-singular-integral-equation)

Comment: Different as the numerical scheme

Comment: @Mutaz Please check `f[x]` and your integral equation (see my comment).  Therewith I could provide you a solution based on Galerkin method...

Comment: @ Ulrich Neumann It is true. Both side of the integral equations have complex values so you will not be able to plot `f[x]`. However, why you need to do so, I think you don't need to plot f. The most important is the exact solution as long as it satisfied both side of the integral equation. Waiting your contribution, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numerical method I suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198675/numerical-solution-of-a-singular-integral-equation/198812#198812) also works for this case.It uses expression describing the integral `Integrate[(x - t)^(-1/4),t]`

```
f[x_] := 1/
    1155 (112 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + 
     x (144 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + 
        x (1155 + 256 (-1 + x)^(3/4) - 
           1280 x^(3/4) - (1155 + 512 (-1 + x)^(3/4)) x + 
           1024 x^(7/4))));
ker[t_, x_] := -(4/3) (-t + x)^(3/4)

np = 101; points = fun = Table[Null, {np}];
Table[points[[i]] = i/np, {i, np}];
sol = Unique[] & /@ points;
Do[fun[[i]] = f[t] /. t -> points[[i]], {i, np}]; sol1 = 
 sol /. First@
   Solve[Table[
     sol[[j]] - 
       Sum[.5*(sol[[i]] + 
           sol[[i + 1]])*(ker[points[[i + 1]], points[[j]]] - 
           ker[points[[i]], points[[j]]]), {i, 1, np - 1}] - 
       Sum[.5*(sol[[i]] + 
           sol[[i + 1]])*(ker[points[[i + 1]], points[[j]]] - 
           ker[points[[i]], points[[j]]])*If[i >= j, 0, 1], {i, 1, 
         np - 1}] == fun[[j]], {j, 1, np}], sol];
u = Transpose[{points, Re[sol1]}];
Show[Plot[x^2*(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue], ListPlot[u, PlotStyle -> Orange]]
```

[image: fig1]

If we use the algorithm that @Mutaz offers, then a solution for n = 2 (for n = 5, a supercomputer is needed) looks like that

```
phi[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x < 1}}, 0]
psi1[x_] := (phi[2 x] - phi[2 x - 1]);
psijk[x_, j_, k_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(Sqrt[2])^j psi1[2^j x - k], 
    0 <= j}, {2^j psi1[2^j (x - k)], j < 0}}]
f[x_] := 1/
    1155 (112 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + 
     x (144 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + 
        x (1155 + 256 (-1 + x)^(3/4) - 
           1280 x^(3/4) - (1155 + 512 (-1 + x)^(3/4)) x + 
           1024 x^(7/4))));
exactsoln[x_] := x^2 (1 - x);
(*u[x]-Integrate[(x-t)^(-1/4)*u[t],{t,0,x}]-Integrate[(x-t)^(-1/4)*u[\
t],{t,0,1}]=f[x];*)
sol[x_, n_] := 

Sum[c[j, k]*psijk[x, j, k], {j, -n, n}, {k, -2^n, 2^n - 1}]
     n = 2;  var = 
     Flatten[Table[c[j, k], {j, -n, n, 1}, {k, -2^n, 2^n - 1, 1}]];np = 
     Length[var]; points = 
     Table[Null, {np}];
    Table[points[[i]] = i/np, {i, np}];
eq = ParallelTable[
    sol[points[[i]], n] - 
      Integrate[(points[[i]] - t)^(-1/4)*sol[t, n], {t, 0, 
        points[[i]]}] - 
      Integrate[(points[[i]] - t)^(-1/4)*sol[t, n], {t, 0, 1}] == 
     f[points[[i]]], {i, 1, np}]; 
{b, m} = N[CoefficientArrays[eq, var]];
sol1 = LinearSolve[m, -b];
u = Sum[c[j, k]*psijk[x, j, k], {j, -n, n}, {k, -2^n, 2^n - 1}] /. 
   Table[var[[i]] -> sol1[[i]], {i, Length[var]}];
Show[Plot[x^2*(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLabel -> Row[{"n = ", n}]], 
 Plot[Re[u], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Orange]]
```

[image: fig2]

I will show another method that is in the middle position between what [Roman](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198675/numerical-solution-of-a-singular-integral-equation/198736?noredirect=1#comment514674_198736) suggested and what the author wants. This method is very accurate.Figure 3 on the right shows the difference between the exact solution and the numerical one with 'n = 3'. This difference is of the order of $10^{-16}$.

```
psijk[x_, j_] := x^j
f[x_] := 1/
    1155 (112 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + 
     x (144 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + 
        x (1155 + 256 (-1 + x)^(3/4) - 
           1280 x^(3/4) - (1155 + 512 (-1 + x)^(3/4)) x + 
           1024 x^(7/4))));
exactsoln[x_] := x^2 (1 - x);
(*u[x]-Integrate[(x-t)^(-1/4)*u[t],{t,0,x}]-Integrate[(x-t)^(-1/4)*u[\
t],{t,0,1}]=f[x];*)

sol[x_, n_] := Sum[c[j]*psijk[x, j], {j, 0, n}]

n = 3; var = Flatten[Table[c[j], {j, 0, n, 1}]]; np = 
 Length[var]; points = Table[Null, {np}];
Table[points[[i]] = i/np, {i, np}];
eq = ParallelTable[
    sol[points[[i]], n] - 
      Integrate[(points[[i]] - t)^(-1/4)*sol[t, n], {t, 0, 
        points[[i]]}] - 
      Integrate[(points[[i]] - t)^(-1/4)*sol[t, n], {t, 0, 1}] == 
     f[points[[i]]], {i, 1, np}]; // AbsoluteTiming

{b, m} = N[CoefficientArrays[eq, var]];
sol1 = LinearSolve[m, -b];


u = Sum[c[j]*psijk[x, j], {j, 0, n}] /. 
   Table[var[[i]] -> sol1[[i]], {i, Length[var]}];
Show[Plot[x^2*(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLabel -> Row[{"n = ", n}]], 
 Plot[Re[u], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Orange]]
Plot[x^2*(1 - x) - Re[u], {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Delta]u"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLabel -> Row[{"n = ", n}]]
```

[image: fig3]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94005/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-trounev-solving-numerically-a-special-singular-inte).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, a little bit late...

This answer shows how to use [Galerkin's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method) to solve the integral equation.

ansatz:

```
g[x_] := Table[x^i, {i, 0, 4}] (* Polynombasis *)
ui = Array[U, Length[g[x]], 0] (* ansatz: u[x]== ui.g[x] *)
```

system matrix (weighted residuals)

```
M = NIntegrate[Outer[Times, g[x], g[x]], {x, 0, 1}] -
NIntegrate[Outer[Times, g[x], g[t]]/(x - t)^(1/4), {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x},Exclusions -> {t == x}] -
NIntegrate[Outer[Times, g[x], g[t]]/(x - t)^(1/4), {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1},Exclusions -> {t == x}]
```

=> left hand side of the discretized integral equation: `M.ui`

right hand side (of the discretized integral equation): `rS`

```
f[x_] := 1/ 1155 (112 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + x (144 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + x (1155 + 256(-1 + x)^(3/4) - 1280 x^(3/4) - (1155 + 512 (-1 + x)^(3/4)) x + 1024 x^(7/4))))
rS= NIntegrate[f[x] g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

=>=> approximation of the solution `u[x]=(Inverse[M].rS).g[x]`

```
p=LinearSolve[M,rS] 
Plot[Re[p].g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

That's it!

Thereby the basis functions can easily be changed, for example to piecewise trianglefunctions. Besides in this example the integration can be done analytically.

**addendum**

With  wavelet-basis:

```
g[x_] := Table[psijk[x, j, k], {j, -n, n}, {k, -2^n, 2^n -1}] /.n -> 2 // Flatten
```

MMA evaluates

[image]

Comment: OK! You just repeated my solution to the equation with `n = 4`. Can you build a solution using functions `psijk[x, j, k]` from @Mutaz post?

Comment: Add definition `f[x_] := 1/
    1155 (112 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + 
     x (144 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + 
        x (1155 + 256 (-1 + x)^(3/4) - 
           1280 x^(3/4) - (1155 + 512 (-1 + x)^(3/4)) x + 
           1024 x^(7/4))));`

Comment: I'm not sure about a repetition: In my attempt there is no pointwise- discretization. Trying to understand the function psijk[x, j, k] ...

Comment: Are you kidding about the  pointwise- discretization for `n=3`? This is a projection of the equation to get n + 1 equations for finding `c[j]`, which is quite equivalent to your system.

Comment: @ Ulrich could you please provide me with a reference or link fir the Galerkin method.

Comment: Also please m, can you add another solution but by considering paijk[x,j,k] instead of g[x]?

Comment: @  Alex Trounev Sorry I'm not kidding, but needed my time to get it. You're right, the systems are equivalent.  Regardless the structure of the system in my answer seems to be much more compact.

Comment: @ Mutaz For n==3 there are 112 different basisfunctions `Table[ psijk[x, j, k], {j, -n, n}, {k, -2^n, 2^n - 1}] // Flatten` which aren't independent. Formally  you can substitude `g[x]=Table[...]`  but you'll get a huge system. Why do you prefer these basiscfunctions?

Comment: I am using it to generalize a numerical scheme